# Custom user attribute for all users in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

Is there a way for all users to create custom users attribute in keycloak (like phone number)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a group and add an attribute to it.

Then set that group as default group. This way the attribute set to the group is available to all the users

Comment: 1. does not work, at least not on 4.6.0.Final ; 2. does not answer the question, which is asking about the ability to add additional unique attribute to each user. your offer to attach single phone number to all users.